# Apply Datenum to a column within table

Tags: matlab

I would like to calculate the time difference between an initial date and the date in the second column of my table.

I have the initial date: bdate '25/05/2017 11:54:21'
 which give me:

```
>> bdateNUM=datenum(bdate,'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS')

>> bdateNUM =
 7.368404960763889e+05
```

Then, I am trying to apply Datenum to the second column ('date') of my table ('rawunstackclean') but I get an error (see below).

```
        Name                   Date             Value  
____________________    ___________________    ________

'AIR_0123_945_03_PT'    25/05/2017 11:54:17     79.5573
'AIR_0123_945_03_PT'    25/05/2017 11:54:18    79.10156
'AIR_0123_945_03_PT'    25/05/2017 11:54:20    79.83941
'AIR_0123_945_03_PT'    25/05/2017 11:54:22    78.99306
'AIR_0123_945_03_PT'    25/05/2017 11:54:25    78.88455
'AIR_0123_945_03_PT'    25/05/2017 11:54:27    79.28241
'AIR_0123_945_03_PT'    25/05/2017 11:54:29    79.07986
'AIR_0123_945_03_PT'    25/05/2017 11:54:31     78.7037
```

Code which causes the error:

```
>> test=datenum(rawunstackclean.Date,'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS');
Error using datetime/datenum
Too many input arguments.
```

Any advice on how to proceed? Thanks.

Comment: Does your `Date` column contain `datetime` variables or `string` variables? If they're `datetime` then you don't need to specify the format string and can (successfully) just call `datenum(mytable.Date)`

Comment: I checked with the 'isdatetime' function and the Date column contains Datetime variable. Removing the the format string has solved the issue! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) you can see you're slightly confusing two input cases of `datenum`.

**What you're trying**:

> `DateNumber = datenum(DateString,formatIn)` uses `formatIn` to interpret the dates and times represented by `DateString`.

So if you were inputting date *strings* (as you are in the single example) then it's useful to provide the format to make MATLAB's interpretation of your date string more robust and predictable.

**What you need**:

In the comments, you've confirmed that the column in your table in fact contains `datetime` type values. MATLAB doesn't need to know the format of these, since it is already storing them internally as a type of time. You can convert them directly using this other method from the docs:

> `DateNumber = datenum(t)` converts the `datetime` values in `datetime` array `t` to serial date numbers.

**Summary**

In short, you can get the result you need using

```
test = datenum(rawunstackclean.Date);
```